# Nonlocal integral

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

I have a little problem with the next integral,
       $$ \int{d^3{\bf r^{\prime}}\left[\frac{exp(-ar^{\prime})}{r^\prime}\right]u({\bf r}-{\bf r^\prime}})=\int{4\pi r^\prime dr^{\prime}exp(-ar^{\prime}) u({\bf r}-{\bf r^\prime}}) $$

where $u(r)$ is an unknown wave function. I found that the integral can be written as 
$$ 4\pi X u({\bf r}) $$

where I assume $X$ is given by
$$ X=\int{ r^\prime{ dr^{\prime}}exp(-ar^{\prime}) } $$
It is not clear to me why $u(r-r')=u(r)$, perhaps a Taylor expansion? Is my assumption wrong? This integral is a second term in a temperature modified Schrodinger equation ($D_1$,$D_2$,$D_3$ are not important for the discussion)

$$\left(E+\frac{\nabla}{2 \mu}\right) u({\bf r})=\frac{e^2D_1}{2r}u({\bf r})+\frac{e^2D_2D_3}{8\pi r}\int{d^3{\bf r^{\prime}}}\left[\frac{exp(-\sqrt{D_2}r^{\prime})}{r^\prime}\right]u({\bf r}-{\bf r^\prime})$$
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Try https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't understand your very first equation; it seems you assume the integrand depends only on the radius $|\mathbf{r}'|$, but the function $u$ depends on the direction of the vector $\mathbf{r}'$ as well.

Comment: Yes, in reality, that is my problem. In the paper I found, they did that; the assumption I did. So, the integral cannot be solved if I do not know the function u?

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation for $u(\bf{r})$ allows for a radial solution $u(r)$, depending only on the norm $r=|\bf{r}|$ of the vector $\bf{r}$. For such a solution we can perform the angular integration,
$$\int d^3{\bf r^{\prime}}\,\frac{\exp(-ar^{\prime})}{r^\prime}u(|{\bf r}-{\bf r^\prime}|)=\int d^3{\bf r^{\prime}}\,\frac{\exp(-a|{\bf r-r^{\prime}}|)}{|{\bf r-r^{\prime}}|}u(r')$$
$$\qquad =2\pi\int_0^\infty dr' u(r')X(r,r')$$
$$X(r,r')=\frac{r'}{ar}\left(e^{-a|r-r'|}-e^{-a(r+r')}\right).$$